# EF6, MysqlDB, and Blazor, Blazor not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have one project that holds db contexts for multiple applications to consume. I created a basic blazor project and tried to create one of my db contexts to test retrieving info and i keep getting this error and the page showing nothing. Any ideas? Context lib is NetCoreApp 3.1 and Blazor web app is NetCoreApp 5.0

```
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 888
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 371
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 110
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 140
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 846
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 410
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 376
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[Boolean,Boolean](Boolean state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator[[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[Boolean](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[Boolean](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[Boolean](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[Type](IQueryable`1 source)
   at WebApplication.Pages.FetchData.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder) in C:\Users\Matth\Documents\GitHub\ProjectAzurite\WebApplication\Pages\FetchData.razor:line 9
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

Comment: You forgot to share any code that causing the error.

Comment: Basic creation of the context that I generated via scaffolding from my db via mysql pomelo. Just calling new AssetContext (extends dbcontext) breaks blazor.

Comment: Yes, those information and codes should be in your post (so that others can help), not in comments.

Comment: That information was in my post: "create one of my db contexts to test retrieving info", you can so see it clearly in the stack trace that its failing when creating the dbcontext due to some odd error. This is less a code issue and more a framework comparability issue and am wondering if there is a workaround.

Comment: "This is less a code issue and more a..." - I didn't think its a "code issue". You should post the related code because code always gives the context around the issue, which helps others to get a better picture about the problem.

Comment: So posting the 'related code' which would be one line of "new AssetContext()" adds enough information for you to get a better picture? If there was more to it I would, but honestly if you couldn't get the gist of the issue from the short explanation and the stack trace idk how to help you. To follow up, if your going to just try to critique the way a question is structured, you probably shouldn't even bother posting a reply and keep scrolling

Comment: Obviously, you are trying to use EF Core on the client side. Instead, do it on the server side, and send the data to the client.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov could you explain more? The application as server sided blazor app, would it not execute on the server by default?

Answer (score 1):

Jetbrains Blazor server app creation is bugged, creating the blazor server app via visual studio has fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but on PostgreSQL.  Seems that not all db drivers have support for blazor wasm; e.g. seems to be also the case for SQL Server (but not for CosmosDb):
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/599

see also: https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/ef-core-and-cosmosdb-with-blazor-webassembly/