# .net 5.0 blazor client app ssh connection

Tags: .net, blazor, ssh.net

Trying to make a ssh connection from within a .net 5.0 blazor client app.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SSH.NET" Version="2020.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then tried sample code ;

```
 try
        {

            byte[] expectedFingerPrint = new byte[] {
                                            0x66, 0x31, 0xaf, 0x00, 0x54, 0xb9, 0x87, 0x31,
                                            0xff, 0x58, 0x1c, 0x31, 0xb1, 0xa2, 0x4c, 0x6b
                                        };

            using (var client = new SshClient(my_ip, my_port, my_username, my_password))
            {
                client.HostKeyReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (expectedFingerPrint.Length == e.FingerPrint.Length)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < expectedFingerPrint.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (expectedFingerPrint[i] != e.FingerPrint[i])
                            {
                                e.CanTrust = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.CanTrust = false;
                    }
                };
                client.Connect();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
```

However received below error;

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Net.NameResolution is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.DnsAbstraction.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.ConnectorBase.SocketConnect(String host, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Connection.DirectConnector.Connect(IConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

In a standard console application this error don't happen.

Is it somehow possible to make a ssh connection from blazor client app?

Comment: When you say blazor client app I assume you mean blazor webassembly.  The exception message is pretty self-explanatory.  Remember, webassembly is heavily sandboxed and there are many libraries that are not possible there.  For starters, ordinary socket connections are not possible in a browser (websockets are the closest you could get, but it's not a replacement for regular sockets).

Comment: Possibly related: [EF6, MysqlDB, and Blazor, Blazor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65975606/850848).